# Function connect() return zero regardless whether it succeeded to connect or not

Tags: c++, tcp

When I use `connect()` function on  i7 computer it always returns zero regardless whether it succeeded to connect or not. I just don't have another application to connect to and it returns zero anyway (server's address 127.0.0.1).

When I run the same application on different computer it behaves correctly. So, what could be problem?

Thank you.

#### Edit Move from Answer below.

#### Code

```
struct hostent* pHostEntry;

pHostEntry = gethostbyname(host);

if(pHostEntry == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

struct in_addr* host_addr = (struct in_addr*) * pHostEntry->h_addr_list;

if(host_addr == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

long sockfd;

if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    return 0;
}

memset((char*) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr  = *host_addr;
serv_addr.sin_port   = htons(port);

if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    CloseSocket();
    sockfd = -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Here it is. Here I always have zero. I, of course checked whether any other application listens om the same port. There is no one. Moreover, if I had one then I couldn't work if my server is on. But when my server is on I don't have any conflicts. i7 -> Intel(R( Core(TM) i7 CPU 930 @ 2,80GHz 2.80 GHz I use this code for a while now. I have several computers with different OS and chips. Only this on (with OS Windows 7) has such a problem. I just wondering if someone has faced the same problem. Thank you

Comment: Some code would really be helpful here.

Comment: Which `connect()` function is this? Can you please paste the code?

Comment: Perhaps some other application happens to listen on the port you connect to. Post some code if you need more help.

Comment: @bmargulies it's an x64 processor from Intel. I hope you knew that.

Comment: Once you got 0 return value from `connect()`, how exactly do you determine that it actually failed?..

Comment: @Rafe I hoped that the OP meant something *relevant*, which a chip name isn't.

Comment: @bmargulies but architecture would be. OP should've said x64

Comment: Of course, `sockfd` should be an `int` and not a `long`, but if you've got all the functions prototyped, the compiler should truncate it for you.  If you don't have all the functions prototyped, you're in for a world of pain - find the options that make sure you do have functions prototyped.

Comment: @Jonathan, since this is Windows, [it should be neither `long` nor `int` but `SOCKET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737625.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible that Windows 7 is returning an IP6 address for the remote server. I suggest you check the value of `pHostEntry->h_addrtype`.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
```

On Unix, that works, because valid file descriptors tend to be small non-negative numbers.  But according to [the documentation for `socket`](http://fuse4bsd.creo.hu/localcgi/man-cgi.cgi?socket+2), `-1` is the only error return code.  Other negative numbers are not errors.

Now you're trying to run this code on Windows, and the assumption that descriptors are small non-negative numbers breaks.

The Windows documentation is very clear.  [`socket` returns `INVALID_SOCKET` in case of error, all other values indicate success.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740506.aspx)